# How to add fruit puree into yogurt without making it too liquid?

Tags: fruit, yogurt

What is the best way to flavor our yogurt with fruit puree without making it too liquid? I desire its consistency would be like the store bought one.

Another question: can we preserve yogurt that has already been added fruit?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to add fruit to yogurt is to use a **jam**, **jelly**, or **fruit preserve** of choice. By cooking out the liquid and thickening with sugar and pectin, a jelly ends up much less watery than a fruit puree. Depending on the fruit you are starting with and the desired texture, the exact recipe will vary. Store-bought jams work as well.

If you are looking for a **fresh** fruit flavor (as opposed to the *cooked* flavor of jam) you still have a few options. You could change the composition of your puree (e.g. by pureeing dried fruits, or choosing a less watery fruit to begin with). You could add a thickening agent that activates without cooking, like pureed chia seeds.

Finally, you could keep your puree as is and use a thicker yogurt: **greek-style** or another **strained** yogurt should be thicker in the first place, and the texture should still be reasonably thick even after mixing in a watery puree.

I am not sure how to answer your preservation question. A mixture of fruit and yogurt should keep decently in the fridge. But if you are trying to preserve it longer, we would need more details about your process.